# Modify dojo chart x axis with real data

Tags: javascript, mysql, dojo, dojox.charting

Question: How can I build an X axis for a dojo chart from a Date column?

I'm trying to create a custom addAxis() function for the x axis of a Dojo multiseries line chart.

Incoming JSON data is stored in an Observable Memory dstore, retrieved via xhr from a PHP script, and looks like:

```
{"Date":1415854800,"Pressure1":23.2312,"Pressure2":17,"Pressure3":0,"Pressure4":0},
{"Date":1415913460,"Pressure1":25.0123,"Pressure2":17,"Pressure3":0.015,"Pressure4":0},...
```

That "Date" field is a Unix epochal timestamp via MySQL's UNIX_TIMESTAMP() on a Date column. It doesn't have to be, but I've tried a lot of recipes and that's the latest one.

My custom function looks like:

```
var data = new Memory({data:myjsondata});
...
labelFunc: function(n) {
    var d = dates.get(n).Date;
    alert(d);
}
```

The "data" object is good as far as addSeries is concerned: addSeries() can plot all 4 pressures correctly. That's the hard part. Usually.

Dojo charts accept dstore, store, and DataTable objects, and probably other data types as well, but the "API Reference" (aka "brief overview/tutorial" in any other project) only provides limited recipes for those objects, and examples of useless hard-coded arrays.

The data objects aren't really documented either, I don't have time to read the source and figure out a hack, and besides, there appear to be many obsolete iterations of data objects. It's easy to get lost and that's exactly where I am.

That **dates.get(n).Date** throws an exception because 'Date' is undefined. According to the most recent documentation for the version I'm using, that's a way to do it. Maybe. If this version of the Memory dstore object documentation isn't in error.

Question: How can I build an X axis for a dojo chart from a Date column?

I can make the data look like anything, but the X axis needs to reflect that Date value, and every other field in the row is a Y axis value for that Date.

Answer (score 0):

The trick, it seems, is to add an "id" column to the JSON MySQL output, and **also** set that id field as the Memory object id via idProperty in the Memory constructor, as in this example:

in the PHP code:

```
...
$stmt = $conn->prepare("@i := 0");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS id, myDate, myVal1, myVal2 FROM T_BlahBlah");
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Might need to convert some "null"s to NULL
// Toss the "null" strings
array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$item, $key) {
    if ($item == 'null' || $item == NULL) $item = NULL;
});
echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Now, your JSON looks like:

```
[{"id":1,"myDate":"2014-12-01","myVal1":2.22,"myVal2":0.77},
 {"id":2,"myDate":"2014-12-02","myVal1":4.92,"myVal2":1.14},...
```

The JavaScript to grab this data looks like:

```
...
function(ready, Chart, StoreSeries, Claro, Legend,
         Default, Markers, Tooltip,
         Magnify, SelectableLegend,
         Memory, Observable, SimpleQueryEngine, lang, arr,
         xhr, domConstruct, dom, aspect){

         xhr.get({
             url: "blahDatum.php",
             sync: true,
             handleAs: "json"
         }).then(function(data){
             store = Observable(new Memory({data:data, idProperty:"id"}));
         });

         // Create the chart within it's "holding" node
         var chart = new dojox.charting.Chart("chartNode");

         // Set the theme
         chart.setTheme(Claro);

         chart.addPlot("default", {
             type: Markers,
             markers: true,
             interpolate: true,
             tension: "X"
         });

         chart.addAxis("x", {
             title: "Date",
             titleOrientation: "away",
             includeZero: false,
             rotation: -30,
             minorTicks: false,
             labelFunc: function(n) {
                 var row = store.get(n);
                 if (row !== null && row !== undefined) {
                     var date = new Date(row.Date);
                     return date.toLocaleDateString();
                 }
             }
         });
         .... // addSeries, legend, etc
```

Everything clicked into place once I set the idProperty in the Memory() constructor.

This answer also explains how you add an X axis using ISO dates from a database.